# Why is nothing displayed in my flutter widget?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, view

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text("Se connecter"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: 
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child : 
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
            ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 160.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ]
            ),
            TextField(  
                decoration: InputDecoration(  
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),  
                    labelText: 'Email',  
                    hintText: 'Enter email',  
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                ),  
            ),
            TextField(  
                obscureText: true,  
                decoration: InputDecoration(  
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),  
                    labelText: 'Password',  
                    hintText: 'Enter Password',  
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                ),  
            ),

            Text(
                '10',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
            // ↓ Add this.
            ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.red,
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                print('button pressed!');
                Map<String,String?> infos = {
                    'app_id' : dotenv.env['app_id'],
                    'database' : dotenv.env['database'],
                    'mail' : dotenv.env['mail'],
                    'pass' : dotenv.env['pass'],
                    //'debug-mr' : dotenv.env['debug-mr'],
                };
                var a = await HttpGet('/auth', infos);
                Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(a.body);
                print(map['auth_mode']);
                },
                child: Text('Next'),
            ),
            ],
        ),
        ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: null,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
```

I want first to create a column in 2 columns in the first row of the view, then display in differents rows differents components after the second row... each one one row

..but there is not that

I expect that it appears anything of my screen view, or nothing is displayed, all is white

Thanks in advance if you are able to help me

Answer (score 0):

Please add shrinkWrap = true inside ListView,
Or Wrap Expand widget outside ListView,
If scrollDirection = axis.horizontal, Please Wrap LisView in SizeBox and set Height for SizeBox

Comment: nothing changed, all screen is white again

Comment: SizedBox(
                  height: 200,
                  child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      children: <Widget>[
                         ....
                      ]),
                ),

Comment: @victorvance2 Let's fix it like this. It will work

Answer (score 0):

Because of `Column [ ListView...]` Firstly check [Unbounded height / width | Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI).

For your case, Container doesn't have any height.

try providing height.

You can wrap the `ListView` with `Expanded` widget, it will get available space for ListView.

```dart
class _FR43State extends State<FR43> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text("Se connecter"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 160.0,
                        height: 200,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 160.0,
                        height: 200,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Email',
                  hintText: 'Enter email',
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  hintText: 'Enter Password',
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                ),
              ),

              Text(
                '10',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
              ),
              // ↓ Add this.
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.red,
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  // print('button pressed!');
                  // Map<String,String?> infos = {
                  //     'app_id' : dotenv.env['app_id'],
                  //     'database' : dotenv.env['database'],
                  //     'mail' : dotenv.env['mail'],
                  //     'pass' : dotenv.env['pass'],
                  //     //'debug-mr' : dotenv.env['debug-mr'],
                  // };
                  // var a = await HttpGet('/auth', infos);
                  // Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(a.body);
                  // print(map['auth_mode']);
                },
                child: Text('Next'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: null,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```